# Splitting of an exact sequence

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, exact-sequence

> Let $(R,\mathfrak m)$ be a Noetherian local ring. Suppose that $x \in \mathfrak m \setminus \mathfrak m^2$.  Is it true that
>   $$
> \frac{\mathfrak m}{x\mathfrak m} \cong \frac{\mathfrak m}{(x)} \oplus \frac{(x)}{x\mathfrak m}?$$

There exists an exact sequence

$$
0 \rightarrow \frac{(x)}{x\mathfrak m} \rightarrow \frac{\mathfrak m}{x\mathfrak m} \rightarrow \frac{\mathfrak m}{(x)} \rightarrow 0$$

and the question becomes: Does this sequence split? If not, what is a counterexample?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: I have tried to improve the readability of your question by fixing the LaTeX syntax in it.  It is possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question. Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.

Comment: @ali1ghanbari: in *part of Theorem 2.2.8 of Bruns-Herzog they prove that *$I/(x)$ is a direct summand of $I/xI$*. maybe it help you.

Comment: @11156 thats can not help me.I dont understand relation between thats proof and my question?in thats proof uses similar notation but not exactly my question.thanks

Comment: At least when $R$ is regular without any modification the proof, which @11156 suggested, shows that your questions has an affirmative answer. Also, I believe the proof can be used to answer your question. One has the inclusion $J \cap (x) \subseteq xI$ when $I = m$.

Answer (score 4):

In $\mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2$ we have $\bar x\ne\bar 0$. Since $\mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2$ is a finite dimensional $R/\mathfrak m$-vector space, there is a basis $\{\bar x,\bar x_1,\dots,\bar x_r\}$ in $\mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2$. By NAK we have $\mathfrak m=(x,x_1,\dots,x_n)$.
Let $\mathfrak a=x\mathfrak m+(x_1,\dots,x_n)$.
Then $\mathfrak a+(x)=\mathfrak m$.
We also have $\mathfrak a\cap(x)=x\mathfrak m$. Let $y\in \mathfrak a\cap(x)$. Then $y=ax=a_0x+a_1x_1+\cdots+a_nx_n$ with $a_0\in \mathfrak m$, so $ax-(a_1x_1+\cdots+a_nx_n)=a_0x\in \mathfrak m^2$. It follows that $a\in \mathfrak m$ hence $y\in x\mathfrak m$.

We get $\dfrac{\mathfrak m}{x\mathfrak m}=\dfrac{\mathfrak a}{x\mathfrak m}+\dfrac{(x)}{x\mathfrak m}$, and $\dfrac{\mathfrak a}{x\mathfrak m}\cap\dfrac{(x)}{x\mathfrak m}=(0)$. This shows that $\dfrac{(x)}{x\mathfrak m}$ is a direct summand in $\dfrac{\mathfrak m}{x\mathfrak m}$.
Furthermore, $\dfrac{\mathfrak a}{x\mathfrak m}\simeq\dfrac{(x_1,\dots,x_n)}{x\mathfrak m\cap(x_1,\dots,x_n)}$. But $x\mathfrak m\cap(x_1,\dots,x_n)=(x)\cap(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, so $\dfrac{\mathfrak a}{x\mathfrak m}\simeq\dfrac{(x_1,\dots,x_n)}{(x)\cap(x_1,\dots,x_n)}\simeq\dfrac{\mathfrak m}{(x)}$.